# How to replace the wavread(file) in matlab r2015a

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run a matlab script and in the line `[s, fs] = wavread(file);`,

I take the following result,

> Warning: WAVREAD will be removed in a future release. Use AUDIOREAD
>   instead.  In wavread (line 62)   In MEDanalysis (line 25)  Error using
>   wavread (line 70) Invalid Wave File. Reason: Cannot open file.

Error in MEDanalysis (line 25)

```
[s, fs] = wavread(file);
```

Comment: (1) Use `audioread` not `wavread`. (2) Your audio file is corrupt or invalid.  The errors that MATLAB generate are quite clear.  It's very hard to misinterpret or misunderstand what they mean.

Comment: @rayryeng, I really wish people would just read the damn message and use some common sense.

Comment: @zelanix oh yes. In an ideal world lol. However, if we stopped having questions like this, a good chunk of my reputation would go missing :p

Answer (score 1):

You have 1 warning and one error:

1. The Warning is about using `waveread` which will be removed in future versions of MATLAB.
   If you want your code to compatible with newer versions of MATLAB, use `audioread`.
2. The error says something about your wave file being corrupted. Can you play it in VLC for instance?